# How to open an event log programmatically (.net, Windows 7 x64)?

Tags: .net, event-log, windows-7-x64

I want to list entries from a log `Microsoft-Windows-Application Server-Applications/Debug`

I tried listing logs using `EventLog.GetEventLogs()` but it only lists logs that are at the "root" level of the logs tree.

I tried `new EventLog("Microsoft-Windows-Application Server-Applications/Debug")` but it doesn't work either.

Is there a magic syntax to specify an event log that is located in a "folder" (as seen in `EventVwr.msc`)?

Comment: Are you referring to the Applications and Services Logs?

Answer (score 0):

I think you might find what you are looking for here.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/magazine/cc163437.aspx

and

http://www.atrevido.net/blog/CommentView,guid,1b0c68ce-d168-4210-86fb-4f2b2126bfc0.aspx

Doesn't look it's going to be a walk in the part, but should get you going.